# How do I copy just one part of a sentence and put it on a text control?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

Alright, so off a website (that I don't own, so I can't modify it), I have this:

```
<body onload="do_cd();">
<div id="main_container">
<div id="main_content">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="well">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">
<p>
<b>
```

And then all the closing tags.

In that `<b>` portion , there is text. How do I extract that text in there and set a string with it?

Comment: I suggest using the HTML Agility Pack, located here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/, alternativly you could also try a regexe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Parse with regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Could a moderator delete this? I contacted another guy who told me how.

Comment: @chipperyman573: The better option would be to show others how you've done it. You can even accept your own answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, thanks for the heads up. I'll accept it in 2 days (when it lets me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I contacted a guy that I know and he told me how to do it for this purpose:

```
string DownloadFileName = Regex.Match(PageSource, DownloadFileLink + "\">(.*?)</a></li></div></ul>").Groups(1).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) It gets the job done perfectly and is very powerful.